# Wordpress hook source

Tags: plugins, hooks, activation

I am trying to understand how plugins are activated. 
`wp-admin\includes\plugin.php`, line 602, there is a call to run a hook called `activated_plugin`

```
do_action( 'activated_plugin', $plugin, $network_wide );
```

I cannot find the source for the hook itself. Where can I find the source for the action that's being executed?

WP ver: 4.3.1

Comment: Try using hookr.io -> http://hookr.io/4.1.1/actions/activated_plugin/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

> There is no code that's being excuted

The long answer is:

> You are suppose to define that code in your own plugin space. You add a activated_plugin hook and within the callable function you specify you define the things you want to happen when your plugin is actived, ie: create database, clean options, throw a few switches ...